# Identifier not found and undeclared identifier

Tags: c++

This i the code i have used and for some reason its saying there are undeclared identifiers

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bool Firstboot = true;
    EntryPoint();
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int MainMenu()
{
    FormatedOut("MainMenu", "Menu1", "Menu1");
}
int Menu1()
{
    FormatedOut("Menu1", "SubMenuOption1", "SubMenuOption1");
}


int EntryPoint() {
    FormatedOut("MainMenu", "Menu1", "Menu1");

    string option;
    cin >> option;
    if (option == "1")
    {
        Menu1();
    }
}

int FormatedOut(string MenuName, string FirstOption, string FirstOptionTarget) {
    cout << "----------------";
    cout << "| " + MenuName;
    cout << "|---------------";
    cout << "|              ";
    cout << "|  " + FirstOption;
    EntryPoint();
}
```

I have codded this in C++ on Visual Studio 2017

The errors i have been getting for the past half an  hour

```
C3861   'EntryPoint': identifier not found  8
C2065   'cout': undeclared identifier   9
C2065   'endl': undeclared identifier   9
C3861   'FormatedOut': identifier not found 15
C3861   'FormatedOut': identifier not found 19
C3861   'FormatedOut': identifier not found 24    
C2065   'string': undeclared identifier 26
C2065   'option': undeclared identifier 26
C2065   'cin': undeclared identifier    27
C2065   'option': undeclared identifier 27
C2065   'option': undeclared identifier 28
C2065   'string': undeclared identifier 34
```

Any help that you can give me will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should probably [get a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), or simply go back to the books, tutorials or class-notes you already have. All of them *should* tell you that things needs to be declared before you can use them.

Comment: In C++, code is read sequentially, from top to bottom.   Identifiers need to be declared BEFORE they are used for the first time.  The first usage of `EntryPoint()` is in `main()`, and it is not declared before that, hence the error.    The fact that `EntryPoint()` is defined later in the file is irrelevant - the compiler hasn't seen it when parsing the content of the `main()` function.  Same for other functions.   (I suspect the code you have posted differs from the code that produces the errors since, as shown, concerns with `cout` and `cin` would not be diagnosed).

Comment: Also check out the infinite recursion you have going on there. Entrypoint calls FormattedOut (side note: which doesn't return anything despite having a non-void return type) and FormattedOut calls EntryPoint. No wonder the linker is unhappy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int EntryPoint();
int FormatedOut(string MenuName, string FirstOption, string FirstOptionTarget);
add this before main() it should work
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write *function prototypes* for the functions that appear *after* they are called in your source file.

I.e. before `main`, write

```
int EntryPoint();
```

and so on. You'll also probably find that `stdafx.h` needs to be the first line of the source file too, depending on your compiler settings (that's the name of the *precompiled header* that MSVC uses).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler reads from top to bottom just like you. When it reaches this line: `EntryPoint();` it has never seen a function called entry point, so it complains. You need to learn about [`function prototyping`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype).

Put a prototype of your function before the use:

```
int EntryPoint();
...
int main()
{
```